# Sorting array before adding new state in existing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, sorting

I am building a simple blog app in react and  I am trying to sort the new array before setting into existing state array and when I try to sort it then It is showing unexpected results and it is not sorting the array the way I am expecting to.

App.js

```
function Blog() {
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

    const fetchBlogs = () => {
        axios.get("/api/blogs/").then((res) => {
             const sortArray = res.data.blogs
             sortArray.sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : -1)

             setBlogs((prev) => {
             return prev.concat(sortArray);
        }); 
       })
    }

    return (
       <>

          {blogs?.map((res) => 
              {res.id}
          )}

       </>
    )
}
```

I am returning last 5 blogs from the database and then after it and then after it.

So First blogs are like :-

```
[
   {
       "id": 190,
       "title": "Last blog"
   },
   {
       "id": 189,
       "title": "Last blog"
   },
   {
       "id": 188,
       "title": "Last blog"
   },
   {
       "id": 187,
       "title": "Last blog"
   },
   {
       "id": 188,
       "title": "Last blog"
   },
]
```

And I am sorting it to show biggest first like `190, 189, 188,...`

It is sorting for the first 5 blogs without any problem, but I load more blogs on click then It is sorting like `187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 190, 189, 188...` which is unexpected.

I tried using `concat` method using

```
        response.sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : -1)

        setBlogs((prev) => {
          return prev.concat(sortArray);
        });
```

**What I am trying to do?**
I am trying to sort the array according to the id with current state and newly fetched state and set into state.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your are calling fetchBlogs after every scroll, i.e at a time 5 blogs, you are making sure your prev is sorted and your sortArray is sorted. But you are not ensuring that your combination of prev and sortedArray is sorted. Which means you would be concatenating two sorted arrays of size 5 each but the entire 10 elements need not be in sorted order.

i.e fetch first instance arrays of ids 10, 7, 11, 4, 6
it gets sorted to 11,10,7,6,4
Second instance fetch retrieves 45, 3, 56, 2 , 1
it gets sorted to 56, 45, 3, 2, 1

now you can concatenating the two will not work.

Rather than sorting and concatenating, it might make sense to concatenate and then sort the entire entry. Now this might have implications to time/cost as the size grows.

```
    const fetchBlogs = () => {
        axios.get("/api/blogs/").then((res) => {

             const sortArray = res.data.blogs

             setBlogs((prev) => {
             var newArray = prev.concat(sortArray);
             return newArray.sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : -1)
        }); 
       })
    }
```

Comment: Yes, You're absolutely right, But How can I insert new array into current array ?

Comment: You mean, insert new array to current array and have the entire array sorted right? Since the concat inserts the new array as expected. It is the sorting that does not happen unless you do the sorting on the entire array.

Comment: Yes. I meant insert new array to current array and then sort

Comment: Something like the code I just updated the answer with. Is it possible to try something in that lines?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But Now it is not setting state. It is showing `[]`

Comment: I am sorry. Is it possible for you to print the value of prev after the sorting to confirm if we are getting things as expected. So remove the return in front of prev.sort, do a print of prev and then return prev.

Comment: It's okay.When I `console.log(prev)` then it is showing **[]**.

Comment: is that before sort or after. Is it that prev had values before sorting and it became empty after sorting?

Comment: It is sorting successfully first 5 blogs but When I set state and print inside setting state instead of return statement then it is showing empty `[]` . It means it is empty inside set state function

Comment: My bad, I have updated the code. The concat result will be a new array instead of existing one. Please check it. I will also double check in a playground

Comment: Thanks again But there are many duplicate records in the array

Comment: Are they valid duplicates? i.e are they returned from the fetch

Comment: I am sorry, yes they are returning from server. Is there anything I can do to remove duplicates

Comment: I might need more details to actually understand the issue. Do you have the code in github or something? The sample you had provided also had the id 188 as duplicates.

Comment: Sorry no code available on github, But they are not returning with the same response but function is calling twice that's why it is setting duplicate records

Comment: It worked, I set state for removing duplicate results before sorting and setting sorting state

Comment: ok good, alternatively you might need to use set. i.e convert array to set after response received and then convert the set back to array before doing a concat and a sort.